# request.getAttributes() in angular js

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I am trying to fetch some of the request attributes in angualar.js.
I am able to fetch the same attributes inside jsp method using request.getAttribute().

I could not figure how to fetch the same inside angular. Could you please let me know the equivalent function of request.getAttribute in angular.

When the user authorize we are setting the user details as attributes and we need to fetch the same in angular.

Answer (score 1):

`$location.search()` will return an object of key-value pairs, the same pairs as the query string.

www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals?pli=1?

```
$location.search() // {"pli": 1}
$location.search().pli // 1
```

Comment: will the $location.search work for post request? I am setting the header from apache webserver.